# Why is Entity Framework Core DbSet.FromSqlRaw returning all rows, regardless of the SQL passed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Part of my app allows an admin to store a raw SQL query to be evaluated periodically. It's validated and sanitized, etc. I'm currently running it in a test, using an in-memory DbContext, with EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory version 6.0.1.

My QueryHandler that evaluates this looks like this:

```
var sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Records rec WHERE rec.RecordID = 3";
var filteredRecords = _DbContext.Records
    .FromSqlRaw(sqlQuery)
    .ToList();
```

Of course, I wrote this specific query to narrow down the possibilities. RecordID is the primary key, and there's only 1 Record in my test data with that RecordID. But, when I debug the test, filteredRecords here is a list of all 7 records in my test data. Any valid sql I pass to FromSqlRaw seems to do nothing. The code always behaves as though I called .ToList() on the DbSet directly. I expect to get a list of 1 Record, which has a RecordID of 3.

Comment: [While some users use the in-memory database for testing, this is discouraged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli). In-memory context works with objects, not SQL.

Comment: In-memory context cannot use SQL. Remember that. Probably `FromSql` is just ignored.

Comment: I am not sure if FromSqlRaw supports parameterization maybe?

Comment: I was not aware that In-memory context couldn't use SQL, and the in-memory context here is just conforming to the codebase I'm working in. I'll find a different approach that doesn't add too much. SQLite In-Memory?

Comment: @KyleAlm I would recommend to look into using [Testcontainers for .NET](https://dotnet.testcontainers.org/) and use the database type you use in the app. But yes, SQLite In-Memory can be an option in some cases.